# Include JS files in folder into Laravel blade template for development

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-elixir

**Question:** I have elixir concatenating and minifying my JS into one file "app.js". However, if possible, I would like to include the non-concatenated versions when my env == "local".

**gulpfile.js**

```
elixir(function(mix) {

        mix.scripts([
            'app.module.js',
            'app.project.module.js',
            'app.widgets.module.js',
            'app.admin.module.js',
            'admin/_common/module.js',
            'admin/_common/forms/module.js',
            'admin/_common/layout/module.js',
            'admin/_common/ui/module.js',
            'components/**/*.js',
            'home/**/*.js',
            'layouts/**/*.js',
            'main/**/*.js',
            'projects/**/*.js',
            'quick-quote/**/*.js',
            'services/**/*.js',
            'users/**/*.js',
            'admin/*.controller.js',
        ], 'public/dist/app.js', 'public/app/')

});
```

**Blade Template:**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  @if(env('APP_ENV') == 'local')

    <!-- Include all of the matching files in my gulpfile.js -->

  @else

   <!-- include my concatenated file if not local -->
   <script src="app.js"></script>

  @endif
```

Comment: Interesting objective. You can't include files from outside your public directory. No matter what clever suggestion follows, you'll have to copy each asset to the public directory with <https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir#copying-files-and-directories>. Once all the JS is in one place, flysystem could make short-work of getting all *.js files.

Comment: @j.steelman Currently all the files are inside the public directory "public/app" is the base directory as the third parameter. I will look into flysystem thanks!

Comment: Oh, I see that now. This isn't a complete recipe - but should get you started: 

collect(Storage::listContents('/public'))->where('type','file')->where('extension','js')->each(function($fileArray) {echo Storage::url($fileArray['path']); });

Comment: @Fostah did u get the solution for this?

Comment: @sujitrulz I ended up just manually including the files, but I'm sure there's a better solution,